# Get objects from array in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have below code

```
var obj = [];
var statuses = [];
var time ='';

statuses array has some values like 
statuses[0] = [1]
statuses[1] = [0]
statuses[2] = [1]
statuses[3] = [1]
```

Now i want to push these values in obj array such that when i do
obj[0].length it should come to 5

If i do obj.push(([time, statuses])) it gives length as 2

When i do `obj.push(([time, statuses[0],statuses[1],statuses[2],statuses[3]]));`
then i am getting value of obj[0].length as 5

I dont want to hardcode the values like statuses[0],[1] in obj.push as i am not sure how many values will be present in statuses array in future.

Ofcourse my status array will grow depending upon the values i receive from backend. So my obj[0].length should be number of objects in status array + time obj.
Eg: if statuses has 8 values then my final obj[0].length should come to 9

I have tried using concat function but their is no luck.

Could anyone please help me out with how can I achieve this dynamically?

Comment: You can use a loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: No. For loop doesnt work for the way i want to push the values in obj. I tried with it also, but it doesnt solve my purpose.

Comment: So you want to push elements in `obj` array in following order: `time`, `statuses[0]`, `statuses[1]`, ... ? Right?

Comment: yes, but these objects should be in obj[0] instance and obj[0].length should equal these values

Comment: *If i do obj.push(([time, statuses])) it gives length as 2* , this is because the status itself is  a array , hence when you refer to `obj` it will be like this
 `obj [
     time, 
     status [
       1,
       2,
       3, 
      ]
   ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var temp = [];
temp.push(time);
foreach(function(s, i, statuses) {
    temp.push(s);
});
obj.push(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should push your elements to first element of `obj` array

```
var obj = [[]];
var statuses = [];
var time ='';

statuses array has some values like 
statuses[0] = [1];
statuses[1] = [0];
statuses[2] = [1];
statuses[3] = [1];

// === SOLUTION ===

obj[0].push(time);
for(var i; i<statuses.length;i++)
{
   obj[0].push(statuses[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**: Answer to another question in comment
Always try to draw and visualize how your arrays could look like when you populate its in your requested way.

```
var obj = [];
var statuses = [];
var time ='';

for(var k=0;k<12;k++)
{
    statuses[0] = [1];
    statuses[1] = [0];
    statuses[2] = [1];
    statuses[3] = [1];

    // === SOLUTION ===

    obj.push([]);
    obj[k].push(time);
    for(var i; i<statuses.length;i++)
    {
       obj[k].push(statuses[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is partially correct, but i am pushing all these values in obj array from a parent for loop. So obj objects instances will depend upon the resultobj length of the object. Now i almost got what i wanted, but when the parent loop runs twice obj[0].length becomes 10 which i dont want.